# What type of BarCode is this?

Tags: c#, barcode, decoding

I am starting the process of writing an application, one part of which is to decode bar codes, however I'm off to a bad start. I am no bar code expert and this is not a common bar code type, so I'm in trouble. I cannot figure out what type of bar code this is, which I have to decode.

I have looked on Wikipedia and some other sites with visual descriptions of different types of bar codes (and how to identify them), however I cannot identify it. Please note that I have tried several free bar code decoding programs and they have all failed to decode this.

So here is a picture of that bar code:

[alt text http://www.shrani.si/f/2B/4p/4UCVyP72/barcode.jpg](http://www.shrani.si/f/2B/4p/4UCVyP72/barcode.jpg)

I hope one of you can recognize it. Also if anyone has worked with this before and knows of a library that can decode them (from an image), I'd love to hear about them.

I'm very thankful for any additional pointers I can receive. Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you just get a barcode scanner?

Comment: I'm using Using C#. Sorry for not mentioning this in the question, however at this point I'm more interested just in identifying this, than actually decoding it.

Comment: I guess because he wants to know what type is it before actually spending some money on hardware that might or might not read the code.

Comment: I'm fascinated but I can't match it against any common barcode types either. What are the barcodes on out of curiosity? Could it be a proprietary system?

Comment: Could you provide a clearer picture? maybe someone as an optical 2D scanner handy and can give it a try.

Comment: Can't you ask the company / organization where this code originates from exactly what type it is, instead of just guessing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

zbar thinks it's Code 128 but the decoded string is suspiciously different than the barcode's own caption. Maybe it's a charset difference?

```
~/src/zebra-0.5/zebraimg$ ./zebraimg ~/src/barcode/reader/barcode.jpg 
CODE-128:10657958011502540742
scanned 1 barcode symbols from 1 images in 0.04 seconds
```

My old copy was called zebra but the library is now called zbar. http://sourceforge.net/projects/zbar/

Comment: Although it might not be... zbar only supports Code 128, Code 39, and Interleaved 2 of 5. I would suggest going to an online barcode generator, plugging your text with and without dashes, and seeing which matches.

Comment: I generated and tested against code 39, code 93, code 128, ean 128, 2of5, postnet, upc-a, upc-e, jan 8 and jan 13 with no obvious results

Comment: Okay, I think I figured it out. Plug in the text with dashes at http://www.morovia.com/free-online-barcode-generator/ and rotate 180 degrees.

Comment: Rotated Code 128 that was evil.

Comment: barcodes are designed to be read forwards and backwards. It's a feature, who knows, maybe the free online barcode generator is backwards.

Answer (score 1):

I don't recognize this bar code - but here are a few sites that might help you (libraries etc.) - assuming you use C# and .NET (you didn't specify in your question):

- http://www.idautomation.com/csharp/
- http://www.bokai.com/barcode.net.htm

Answer (score 1):

It looks a bit like Code 128 but http://www.onlinebarcodereader.com/ does not recognize it as such. Maybe the image quality isn't good enough.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java:

http://code.google.com/p/zxing/

Open Source, supports multiple types of barcodes

A list of software can be found here:

http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Software/Bar_Code/Decoding/

Answer (score 0):

IANABCE (I Am Not A Barcode Expert), but looking at the barcodes [here](http://www.barcodefaq.com/BarcodeMatch/index.html), I'd say this looks closest to the UCC/EAN-128 symbology, character set 'C'.

Do you know what the barcode is used for? What's the application domain?